# jquery or javascript regex pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

i would like to check string using js's regex. i would like write a pattern which is like this; if string contains [^a-zA-Z0-9_] return must be **true** else return must be **false**.

Thank you very for your help already now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `.test`:

```
/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/.test(str);
```

Edit:

```
/[^a-zA-Z0-9_İıĞğÇçÖöÜüÖö]/.test(str);
```

However, your regular expression will basically check whether there is a character that's not in that list in your string. I don't see the practical use of that. Is it indeed what you're trying to acoomplish?

e.g. `a` will fail, `a-` will not fail because the `-` does match the regexp.

Edit 2: If you want to make sure the string contains only certain characters, use this:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-İıĞğÇçÖöÜüÖö]*$/.test(str);
```

What it does is checking whether there are one or more of the characters of that list in the string, and `^...$` means that it only matches the complete string, so that `a%` or something like that does not pass (otherwise it would match the `a` and return `true`).

Edit 3: If a string should not contain any of a list of characters, use e.g.:

```
/^[^İıĞğÇçÖöÜüÖö]*$/.test(str); // returns true if there are not any of those characters in the string
```

Comment: Thank you, One more question how to exclude İıĞğÇçÖöÜüÖö chars from a string?

Comment: Clearly, i just want to the string contains only english chars (uppercase or lowercase), numbers and specials chars like "_- ". My default languge is Turkish.

Comment: i would like to the string does not contains **İıĞğÇçÖöÜüÖöŞş%&** if string contains any chars of this array "İıĞğÇçÖöÜüÖöŞş" callback return me **false** with using js.

Comment: @Kerberos: Oh that is a different question. I thought you wanted to combine them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and sorry.

Comment: Hi again, i think something is wrong. Simya-MVI_4954.AVI return false.

Comment: @Kerberos: I forgot a character :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var string = 'Hello Sir';
var isMatch = /[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/.test(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return /\w/.test(string); // matches Letters,Numbers,and underscore.
```